# Node js Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

When I call node filename.js then it return an error.(Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier).

[image]

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: make sure to save your file before running it

Comment: Yes, I saved my file

Comment: Check if your current directory contains the file in powershell first.

Comment: Yes. I checked this also

Comment: https://prnt.sc/19q1rh7
Look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside the node command mode after you type `node`, you should quit with `Ctrl + C` and you only need to run your js file in the terminal with `node jsfile.js` instead of running in the node command mode.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was in node mode when I switched to terminal mode then code works.
thank you very much